# DIV not expanding to content if some long text put into it

Tags: html, css

I have a white centered container DIV which should be at least 100% of the window in height, but if the text inside is longer, the DIV should expand to fit the content. Instead, the part of text that exceeds the window's height, runs into the grey background.

I tried some of your suggestions I've read such as putting `min-height`s instead of `height`s in the `body`,`html` and `#cntr`, but the white container disappeared completely. Adding `overflow:hidden` to the `#cntr` simply cuts the text to the size of the window, making part of it completely invisible.
Here's my code (without some CSS that's not particularly important here):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="charset=UTF-8">

<style type= "text/css">
html{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {font-family: Georgia; height:99%; margin: 0.25% 0}
div {position: absolute}
#cntr {
    width: 1250px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    height:100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #708090">
<div id="cntr">
<div style="right: 0; top: 0; width:100%; height: 261px; border-bottom: solid 1px black">
<a href="index.html"><img src= "png/logojan2.png" style="position: absolute; top:55px; left: 240px"></a>
<img src="png/rze.png" style="position: absolute; right: 50px; bottom:24px">
</div>

<div style="top: 300px; left: 50px; height: 60%; width:300px">
<div style="position: fixed; background-color: black; height: inherit; width: inherit">
</div>
</div>

<div style="top:300px; left:400px; width:800px">
/*some long <p>'s of text here*/
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the page after scrolling down (the white DIV should stretch to the bottom of the page):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TojZT.png)

Thanks for any suggestions on how I can fix my problem.

Comment: `div {position: absolute}` inside your `<style>` tag applies to every single `division element` in your page. You really want to use a more specific selector. As a sidenote, you only have two alternatives here: 1. Hire a front-end developer. 2. Learn CSS.

Comment: @Rob Actually there is - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Provide you full code with concerned text and better with screenshots of what you have and what you want. Then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @Gaurav Mahindra Added a screenshot of what happens after scrolling down.

Comment: @GauravMahindra Added a screenshot. Sorry for doubling but I'm afraid you weren't notified because of the space in username

Comment: Ok,  got it. Just one last thing. Where are you putting this paragraph. I mean in which div. Provide the paragraph in concerned div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem!

I've read somewhere that elements with `position: absolute` are **taken out of the page flow**, and thus are considered **zero-height** for `min-height` purposes. I also tried setting `min-height: 200px` for `#cntr`, and a small white block appeared. I still don't know why the `min-height: 100%`made the white div disappear completely, but now it works well.

So, changing the

```
div {position: absolute}
```

to

```
div (position: relative}
```

adjusting the coordinates accordingly and setting `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` for `#cntr` solved the problem for me.

Thanks for all help and ideas and hope this answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

give that text style and in css put word-wrap

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: It didn't change anything. Also, I think the problem isn't in the text itself, but in the div containing it or in `#cntr`.